# Panning is slow and laggy. So is crosshair

Tags: highcharts

I am experiencing performance issues in Highstock. Panning and crosshair are slow and laggy on the dataset of 3000 points. Could you please recommend something on this? 
P.S. Unfortunately, enabling datagrouping is not an option.

http://jsfiddle.net/yekaterinabindyuk/zfga80h9/41/

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    animation: false,
    panning: {
      type: 'xy',
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    enableButtons: false
  },
  candlestick: {
    // Performance optimization settings
    animation: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    shadow: false,
    threshold: null

  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1,
    inputEnabled: false,
    buttonTheme: {
      visibility: 'hidden',
    },
    labelStyle: {
      visibility: 'hidden',
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    startOfWeek: 0,
    crosshair: {
      snap: false,
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      snap: false,
    },
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: candleData,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Have you considered to use the boost module? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it didn't help

Comment: I am afraid that there is no chance to improve the performance without enabling the data grouping for such big data.